# HP ALM - Business Process Testing - UFT wont run multiple Flow Iterations

Tags: alm, uft14

I have set up a Business Process Test with multiple Flows in it. For one Flow I set 3 Iterations with different Parameters and I expected UFT to run the flow, well, 3 Times but it only ever does 1 and I have no clue why. What am I missing here? The Picture shows the Execution Plan for the BPT.

Test Canvas
[image: Test Canvas]

Thanks in Advance,
Hans

Comment: It appears to be a bug in ALM, we opened a Ticket.